# session.upload_progress.enabled not in php.ini file

Tags: php

I have php version 5.4.3, yet session.upload_progress.enabled is not in my php.ini
if i do:

```
$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . ini_get("session.upload-  
       progress.name");      }
echo $key;
```

I get "upload_progress_" How can this be and is there anything I can do?

Comment: -1 the above code doesn't parse (where's the matching `{`?) - as is, it wouldn't give an undefined variable warning - please show your _actual_ code.

Comment: Odds are, the matching `{` is preceded by an `if` whose condition is not met.

Comment: sorry, that was another part of the code, I have updated the post

Comment: @michel-feldheim rolled back: please don't put your assumptions in the question.

Comment: Not an assumption, the bracket was just misleading and not part of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [PECL extension uploadprogress](http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress)

e.g.

```
$ pecl install uploadprogress
```